# how to integrate facebook js login and laravel socialite?

Tags: facebook, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

i'm  facebook js sdk for users login,
at the server side i want to get the user data 
i'm trying to use

```
Socialite::with('facebook')->user()
```

to make it work it need 2 query string code and status 
in my JavaScript i'm using the following

```
var auth_status_change = function(response) {

        console.log(response);
        if(response.status == "connected")
        {
            window.location = "{{URL::to(App::getLocale()."/fb_login")}}?code="+??+"&state="+???;
        }

    }
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', auth_status_change);
```

how to get the state and code values to create a valid callback URL for socialite

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to combine 2 things that do the same thing, but one on the server side and one on the client side, that won't work.

Laravel Socialite uses your app token to redirect your user to Facebook, authorize your app to use Facebook on their behalf (token) and provides you with user data. With the token you can do API calls from Laravel.

The Facebook JS SDK does the same thing, but in the browser. It fetches a token which it uses to do API calls.

Check out https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/9 on how Socialite works.

Unless you are using the JS SDK functionality, you can leave it out and just add a link to a socialite route which redirects it to Facebook. That call will provide you with the code and state required to fetch the user.